# React Native cancel animation delay when component will unmount

Tags: animation, react-native, settimeout, delay

I've a little problem with an animation. I try to do a Flash Bar Info on my app for the errors. So to do that I create a new component, this component can be place in one specific view or not, and when the error is trigger from my store the state of my component is change by `componentWillReceiveProps` and set to visible if there is an error message.

So, if there isn't an error message my render function return false value but if there is an error message I run my render function with this animation code:

```js
// Ease in ease out anitmation
Animated.sequence([
  Animated.timing(this.state.translateY, {
    toValue: 40,
    easing: Easing.bounce, // Like a ball
    duration: 450,
  }),
  Animated.delay(3000),
  Animated.timing(this.state.translateY, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 300,
  }),
]).start(() => {
  this.props.clearMessage();
  this.setState({ visible: false }); // <-- Problem is here
});
```

If I stay on my view during the animation delay, that's work perfectly, but if I go to my previous view when the message is set to visible, the function `setState` is called when my component is not mounted.
So I got this waring:

```js
Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.
```

It's a normal behavior because the component is not mounted at this point.
So, I try to find a way to cancel my animation sequence when the component will unmount.

During my research I find a temporary way by using `setTimeout()` function with `clearTimeout` when the component will unmount, but I can't find how to do that with `Animated.delay` function in an `Animated.sequence`, is it possible ?

In advance thank you for your answers!

TLDR;

It is possible to cancel an animation delay when component will unmount ?

Comment: The docs mention a `stopAnimation` method. Have you tried looking into it ? It's [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#stopanimation).

Comment: Thanks Hamaide, but, Yes I also try it, but the function `stopAnimation` is not found for `Animated.sequence`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you give to `Animated.start()` is called with an object declaring whether the animation ran to the end successfully. React-Native also implicitly cancels your animation if the component is unmounted. So check for the `finished`-property in your callback, and only `setState` if the animation ran to the end.

So this should work:

```js
...

]).start((done) => {
  if (done.finished) {
    this.props.clearMessage();
    this.setState({ visible: false });
  }
});
```

(Note that if you manually stop the animation, using e.g. `Animated.stop()` or by starting another animation with the same `Animated.Value`, the `finished`-property will also then be `false`.)

See: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html#working-with-animations