# Should I explicitly stop React Native animations on unmount?

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Suppose I'm starting an animation with `Animated.timing().start()`, doesn't matter when exactly (on mount, or on some external event). Then I'm using an `Animated.View` to render the animation.

Suppose it does not complete before the component unmounts.

Should I explicitly call `stop()` on the animation (and indeed, all animations that could still be running) on unmount, or will it get cleaned up implicitly? Most manually allocated resources don't get implicitly deallocated (unless they're attached to the component, like hooks), but it seems like animations do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find any documentation about this, but I had a look through the code of the version we're using (0.59.8).

The short answer is **no**, there is no need to stop animations explicitly, it is managed by React Native.

The long answer follows my code analysis below.

- When you start an animation for a certain value, that animation is bound to the `Animated.Value`. (either as `_animation`, or as `_tracking`.)
- When you use the `Animated.Value` on an `Animated.Component`, the value is attached to the component as `_propsAnimated`.
- On componentWillUnmount `_propsAnimated` is `__detach`ed, and `__detach` on the `Animated.Value` stops the animation by calling `Animated.Value.prototype.stopAnimation` (which is a public function of Animated.Value).

Comment: Thanks for the code analysis - it does bring clarity to the question. Here's the  [Animated.Value source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/nodes/AnimatedValue.js) if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. My humble opinion would be - **no**. As you probably read [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated), there is no mention that you should do it and when you should do it.
As stated in documentation:

> Animations are started by calling start() on your animation. start()
>   takes a completion callback that will be called when the animation is
>   done. If the animation finished running normally, the completion
>   callback will be invoked with {finished: true}. If the animation is
>   done because stop() was called on it before it could finish (e.g.
>   because it was interrupted by a gesture or another animation), then it
>   will receive {finished: false}.

From this, I would say that when component is unmounted, animation is interrupted. Personally, I didn't used `stop()` in my apps and never faced memory leaks because of it. Problem may occur if you try to change components state in `start()` callback function. That's where `finished` property of the callback function comes in hand. Extra reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562635/2895571).